# Grease Pencil not responding

Tags: draw-mode

I’m using Blender 2.93.5 (after leaving UPBGE behind), and I’m trying to use the Draw mode in the Grease Pencil, but it simply doesn’t respond: I draw, the pointer crosses the screen, but nothing happens.

Does anyone has an idea on why it’s behaving like that? (Or NOT behaving, whatever…)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new version of Blender you have to explicitly create a keyframe for the layer you want to draw on (press I on the 3D window in Draw mode), or enable the Autokeyframe Record button on the timeline to go back to the previous automatic new keyframe creation.

Comment: That works! Thanks for the explanation. 